# way to roll back to a state prior latest software update

Tags: apt, updates, mouse, touchscreen

I have been having this issue for a while where the mouse pointer suddenly starts jumping to top right corner and poping the system menu all the time. Gnome becomes unusable and i can only putty to my ubuntu system.  I disable the touchscreen as per how-to's found on forum.  I could never really find the real reason for this bug and i ended up reinstalling all the time which only worked fine for a while.  I am suspecting a buggy software update so i disable auto update and would inspect the update proposed list for graphic or acceleration update manually to prevent thos update to install.  My system been stable for 3 weeks that way but today i must have miss the faulty update and went forward with the base system update proposed.  and the bang! a few minutes after the mouse pointer start screwing around.  all point to this latest update.  I am new to linux and i would like to roll back to system level before latest update applied this morning.  is it possible.  Note a can only putty.  Ubuntu 20.04, Dell Presicion M6600., thanks for you help.  only info i could find dated 12 year ago.

Comment: Are you saying that the new update was from *today*?  You can "roll back" updates but it's very tricky, and we won't know which package specifically introduced the instability.  Which means other packages may get reverted as well.  (It's also a little difficult if your system cleaned out old versions as well, then there's no installers to revert to)  Start by including the output of `sudo tail -n 50 /var/log/apt/history.log` to your question as an edit, we need to see what was 'most recently updated'.

Comment: If your *"mouse pointer suddenly starts jumping to top right corner and poping the system menu all the time"* you may have installed a Gnome Shell extension that's causing the problem. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Your updates from today did not cause a problem that you have been dealing with "for a while".  Even if it was, downgrading packages is not a path forward.

Comment: A question about how to troubleshoot the mouse issue might be more productive. We get the same updates, but don't have the same problem.

Comment: @heynnema ls: cannot access '/home/brochet/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions': No such file or directory and ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jul 31 12:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Nov 18 01:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 18 01:05 desktop-icons@csoriano
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jul 31 12:29 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Nov 24 11:13 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

Comment: @heynnema So nothing out of the ordinary.  I must say thought that for now the mouse and cursor behaviour came back to normal, to come back god knows when and why.

Comment: So it's working now? Did you reboot?

Comment: Just an update on this to says that I found the source of the problem....  I have a neon desk lamp that is somewhat close to the touchscreen. no kidding.  I can have it on all day but when it gets darker in the evening that is when the moose pointer goes nuts.  Turn off the light its all good. turn it back on and problem is back.  relocated the lanp further and all been normal sine then (several weeks ago)  That is a good one.